# Unzipping and reading shape file in R without rgdal installed

Tags: r, spatial, shapefile, rgdal

I would like to unzip and read in a shape file from the web in R without relying on rgdal. I found the `read.shp` function of the `fastshp` package that can apparently accomplish this without rgdal installed in the environment, however, I'm having trouble implementing.

I would like a function that can unzip and then read in the shape file akin to what's found in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967722/download-and-read-shapefile-function-in-r) post but for the `read.shp` function. I tried the following but to no avail:

```
dlshape=function(shploc, format) {
  temp=tempfile()
  download.file(shploc, temp)
  unzip(temp)
  shp.data <- sapply(".", function(f) {
    f <- file.path(temp, f)
    return(read.shp(".", format))
  })
}

shp_object<-dlshape('https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2017/COUNTY/tl_2017_us_county.zip', 'polygon')
 Error in read.shp(".", format) : unused argument (format)
```

I also tried the following:

```
  dlshape=function(shploc) {
      temp=tempfile()
      download.file(shploc, temp)
      unzip(temp)
      shp.data <- sapply(".", function(f) {
        f <- file.path(temp, f)
        return(read.shp("."))
      })
    }

 shp_object<-dlshape('https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2017/COUNTY/tl_2017_us_county.zip')

Error in file(shp.name, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In file(shp.name, "rb") : 'raw = FALSE' but '.' is not a regular file
2: In file(shp.name, "rb") :
 Show Traceback
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in file(shp.name, "rb") : cannot open the connection
```

I suspect it has to do with the fact that in the function `read.shp()` I'm feeding it the folder name and not the .shp name (for `readOGR` that works but not for `read.shp`). Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `unzip()` from utils and `read_sf()` from sf to unzip and then load your shapefile. Here is a working example:

```
# Create temp files
temp <- tempfile()
temp2 <- tempfile()

# Download the zip file and save to 'temp' 
URL <- "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2017/COUNTY/tl_2017_us_county.zip"
download.file(URL, temp)

# Unzip the contents of the temp and save unzipped content in 'temp2'
unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)

# Read the shapefile. Alternatively make an assignment, such as f<-sf::read_sf(your_SHP_file)
sf::read_sf(temp2)
```