# Can't read shp file in R

Tags: r, r-sf

I tried to open an shp file on my Mac, using this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(rgeos)
sf_trees_raw <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-01-28/sf_trees.csv')
temp_shapefile <- tempfile()
download.file("https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2017//ROADS/tl_2017_06075_roads.zip", temp_shapefile)
sf_roads <- unzip(temp_shapefile, "tl_2017_06075_roads.shp") %>%
  read_sf()
```

But I receive this error message:

```
Error: Cannot open "/Users/name/Documents/Playground/Trees_SF/tl_2017_06075_roads.shp"; The source could be corrupt or not supported. See `st_drivers()` for a list of supported formats.
```

I tried other shp files, and I receive the same error message:

```
map <- read_sf("per_admbnda_adm1_2018.shp")
Error: Cannot open "/Users/name/Documents/Playground/Trees_SF/per_admbnda_adm1_2018.shp"; The source could be corrupt or not supported. See `st_drivers()` for a list of supported formats.
```

I tried copying the shx and dbf files but it doesn't fix the problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try unzipping the whole download first, then reading the shapefile file. Although for `sf` you only need to point at the `.shp` file, all the other ones (`.cpg`, `.prj`, `.shx`, etc) need to be unzipped and in the same directory.

```
temp_shapefile <- tempfile()
download.file("https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2017//ROADS/tl_2017_06075_roads.zip", temp_shapefile)
unzip(temp_shapefile)

sf_roads <- read_sf('tl_2017_06075_roads.shp')
```

Comment: Hello @cnicol, thank you very much! I can't understand why the piping couldn't work but your proposed solution works fine!. The only thing that I don't understand is why if I copied all the files you mentioned in the working directory it couldn't read the shp file. Any

Comment: I think if you specify a file in `zip` then it will only unzip the one file, so when you pipe to `read_sf` it can only find the one file. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59741450/12400385) is a similar answer, but they send the unzipped files into a new folder

Comment: Thank you, now I understand why it couldn’t work! It was just reading one file.

Comment: What about the last section of code where you were trying to open a shapefile that wasn't a zip file? I'm having the same problem on a mac, trying to open a shapefile that has all necessary files together.