# R: Can't download .zip from url

Tags: r, zip

I'm trying to download the following zip from the Internet and extracting a .shp file from it:
https://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/archives/ero/20181227/shp_94e_2018122701.zip

And inside the .zip file, I'm trying to extract the .shp file: 94e2701.shp

(I want to do this in R so I can automate this process to download .shp files for several dates).

Based on some reading, here is the code I've tried:

```
shp_url = "https://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/archives/ero/20181227/shp_94e_2018122701.zip"
tmp = tempfile()

download.file(shp_url,tmp,mode="wb")
# I have also tried without the "mode" argument but have gotten the same result

f_name = "94e2701.shp"
data <- sf::st_read(unz(tmp,f_name))
# Error: Cannot open "3"; The file doesn't seem to exist.
unlink(tmp)
```

When I go to the location of the temp file, I see it's this: "file1b9026cd6821", but it's not a .zip, so I can't extract anything from it/go inside it.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help or guidance is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Similar to this question, but a more thorough answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61282885/12400385

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BLUF: you need more than just the `.shp` file. Unzip more (all) of the files and you'll get differing results.

For each below, I'm using `unzip` on the command line to unzip only the files in the step. In between, I remove files not being tested. I do not believe there is a way in R to `unz(..)` in order to get to all files.

1. Just `94e2701.shp`: error
2. `.shp` and `.prj`: error
3. `.shp` and `.dbf` file: error
4. `.shp` and `.shx`: partial success, does not fill `CRS`

   ```r
   data <- sf::st_read("94e2701.shp")
   # Reading layer `94e2701' from data source `C:\Users\r2\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpqoj4GE\94e2701.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
   # Simple feature collection with 2 features and 0 fields
   # Geometry type: POLYGON
   # Dimension:     XY
   # Bounding box:  xmin: -100.4 ymin: 28.27 xmax: -91.4 ymax: 39.77
   # CRS:           NA
   ```
5. `.shp`, `.shx`, and `.dbf`: same as 4, no `CRS`
6. `.shp`, `.shx`, `.dbf`, and `.prj`: ***success***

   ```r
   data <- sf::st_read("94e2701.shp")
   # Reading layer `94e2701' from data source `C:\Users\r2\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpqoj4GE\94e2701.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
   # Simple feature collection with 2 features and 7 fields
   # Geometry type: POLYGON
   # Dimension:     XY
   # Bounding box:  xmin: -100.4 ymin: 28.27 xmax: -91.4 ymax: 39.77
   # Geodetic CRS:  GCS_Sphere_EMEP
   ```

Incidentally, the thing that made me check this is one paragraph in `?sf::st_read`:

> Note that stray files in data source directories (such as `*.dbf`) may lead to spurious errors that accompanying '*.shp' are missing.

This made me wonder if the presence of other files in the directory were causing your problem.

I do not believe there is a way in R to `unz(..)` in order to get to all files. If you don't want to unzip them into your current directory (just "look" at the files and discard later), then you can create a temp *directory*, unzip into that, and open the file from there.

```r
dir.create(td <- tempfile())
unzip(tmp, exdir = td)
data <- sf::st_read(file.path(td, f_name))
# Reading layer `94e2701' from data source `C:\Users\r2\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpqoj4GE\file185581a1d4d01\94e2701.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
# Simple feature collection with 2 features and 7 fields
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -100.4 ymin: 28.27 xmax: -91.4 ymax: 39.77
# Geodetic CRS:  GCS_Sphere_EMEP
```

Comment: @ r2evans: great answer! I am working on a similar problem with shapefile in R - can you please take a look at it if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75923204/calculating-distances-between-points-on-a-shapefile thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Appreciate the thoroughness and detail of your answer.